# ArCore not able to detect surface on supported android devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, surface, ar-foundation

ArCore not able to detect surface on supported android devices. In Some devices the surface is getting detected but it is taking very long time i'm Testing in moderate light the light is not very high or not very low.

Device Name on which im testing:-

1. Galaxy M32 In this device the surface is getting detected but it take very long time.
2. ReadMi Modelno:- RMX2151 In this device the surface is not getting detected at all.

but when i try any Ar app which uses unity AR Foundation SDK the surface is getting detected in both device's.Ar Unity app which is working for both devices https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ignatiusDevStudio.ARMeter

Im using implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.39.0'